# How to put extra item selected from recyclerview to spinner of new activity in android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-studio-2.3

Hi Guys today i have a problem to display item selected from recylerview in searchActivity and i want to a spinner of EditProfileActivity to be destination displaying it.but in another case i'm using the radiogroup and it's works.

This my codes in searchActivity:

```
User item = usersList.get(position);                            
Intent mIntent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("gender", item.getGender());
```

And this my code in EditProfileActivity

```
searchableSpinner     = (SearchableSpinner)findViewById(R.id.searchableSpinner);
radioGroup            = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_gender);
maleRadioButton       = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_male);
femaleRadioButton     = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_female);
 final Intent data = getIntent();
 if (null != data) {
 String gender = data.getExtras().getString("gender");
 if (gender.equals("Male")){
     maleRadioButton.setChecked(true);
   } else if (gender.equals("Female")){
     femaleRadioButton.setChecked(true);
  }
  /*
   my plan this place for spinner and i'm confused what am i doing?
   */
     }

and its works but today i want to change "RADIOGROUP" to "SPINNER" 
where the list of gender i created it in 

list_ofgender.xml

<resources>
    <string-array name="gender">
        <item>Male</item>
        <item>Female</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>

anyone has solved the problem like this? thanks, i hope to all my friends in this group.
```

And i tried to change and run the below code but still doesn't work.

```
    searchableSpinner     = (SearchableSpinner)findViewById(R.id.searchableSpinner);
final Intent data = getIntent();
     if (null != data) {
     String gender = data.getExtras().getString("gender");

     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
     ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,Integer.parseInt(gender), 
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
searchableSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
if(gender.equals("Male")){
    int position = adapter.getPosition(gender);
    searchableSpinner.setSelection(position, true);
   }else{
    int position = adapter.getPosition(gender);
    searchableSpinner.setSelection(position, true);
   }
}
```

Comment: To senior android programmer help me please..i need help you all.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide to populating a Spinner via SpinnerAdapter here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.

Then use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner#setSelection(int) in order to set the value. You may have add some logic that maps the Intent extra to the expected position.

Comment: can you help me?,The item selected from recylerview is true position but i got error java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Male" at java.lang.Integer.parseInt ,at EditProfileActivity.

Comment: You need to set the selection to the position not the String value.

Comment: i tried to change ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,"Integer.parseInt(gender)", to ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.list_ofgender.xml) but the result is nothing(item in spinner not selected)

Comment: thanks to Troy my problem solved. just how to trigger a spinner to selected position in oncreate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <string-array name="gender">
    <item>Select Gender </item>
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>
    </string-array>


if(searchableSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
{
//Show toast please select gender 
}
else{
if(gender.equals("Male")){
    int position = adapter.getPosition(gender);
    searchableSpinner.setSelection(position, true);
   }else{
    int position = adapter.getPosition(gender);
    searchableSpinner.setSelection(position, true);
   }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks @Prateek Bhardwaj for response, i will trying your solution.

Comment: i selected of gender"Male" from recyclerview , it still doesn't works. the system always reading (Select gender) / 0 position.

Comment: if  i am using  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,"Integer.parseInt(gender)" 
the system got error "invalid int "Male".

Comment: thanks to @Prateek Bhardwaj my problem solved. just how to trigger a spinner to selected position in oncreate.

Comment: searchableSpinner.setSelection(0); you can use it. But set spinner adapter before using this statement.